# print 2D char array with void function

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array, printing, void

I have a 2D char array and I am trying to print it with a void function but it is showing an error

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
void printt(int x, int y, char[][] matrix){
for(int i = 0; i< x; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<y; j++){
        std::cout<<matrix[i][j];
    }
}
}

int main(){
int n = 4,m = 4;
char mat[n][m];
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<m;j++){
        std::cin>>mat[i][j];
    }
}
printt(n,m,mat);
}
```

The code is given above. It prints fine when i use 2 for loops. Can anyone tell me where i am wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Standard c++ doesn't allow variable length arrays. Also, `char[][]` doesn't do what you expect. Suggest exploring with a debugger and studying array declarations with regard to parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not call the function `printt(mat);` like that, the function requires 3 parameters, you are just giving 1...
is defined as

```
void printt(int x, int y, char[][] matrix)
```

so you have to do instead:

```
printt(n, m, mat);
```

Comment: I have done that but it is still showing an error "multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first"